# Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, hashmap

Im using listview on android, below code is giving error after clicking on a list item for another new activity

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // getting list view size
                int size = parent.getCount();

                // initializing array according to list view size
                String[] all_pid = new String[size];
                String[] all_name = new String[size];
                String[] all_address = new String[size];
                String[] all_latitude = new String[size];
                String[] all_longitude = new String[size];

                // looping data into array according to getItemAtPosition
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> extractor = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    // fill data into array
                    all_pid[i] = extractor.get("pid");
                    all_name[i] = extractor.get("name");
                    all_address[i] = extractor.get("address");
                    all_latitude[i] = extractor.get("latitude");
                    all_longitude[i]=extractor.get("longitude");
                }

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivityMainFragment.class);

                in.putExtra("APid", all_pid);
                in.putExtra("AName", all_name);
                in.putExtra("AAddress", all_address);
                in.putExtra("ALatitude", all_latitude);
                in.putExtra("ALongitude", all_longitude);
                // added size for initial view pager initialization
                in.putExtra("size", size);
                in.putExtra("QUOTES", position);
                Log.v(DEBUG, "position Passed: " + position);
                startActivity(in);
            }
```

Error shown is:

```
05-27 15:30:12.985: E/AndroidRuntime(23905): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
05-27 15:30:12.985: E/AndroidRuntime(23905):    at com.example.fightvaw.jsontest.MainActivity$4.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:226)
```

how to solve these type of error ?

Comment: Where is the line 226? edit: owh I think it's "HashMap<String, String> extractor = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);"

Comment: HashMap<String, String> extractor = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);

Comment: I believe the problem is that java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Comment: That means that getItemAtPosition(i) returns an Integer

Comment: Why don't you store data sent to the listView (via an arrayAdapter) as a member variable and then access them via yourList.get(position)?

Comment: what @GregEnnis said, did you try to add to hashmap an Integer? you can add it like Integervalue + ""

Comment: please give me solution im new on java

Comment: What do you have in the list passed to the adapter? Integers?

Comment: Try to access list item base on position which you set as adapter data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is previous code on my custom adapter:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (position);
}
```

and this is solved code in my custom adapter:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(position);
}
```

in which `data`is defined as `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
HashMap<String, String> extractor = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

causes your crash. `parent` is an AdapterView and returns an Integer if you call `getItemAtPosition(i)`.

You can fix this by replacing `parent` with your ListAdapter (which you needed to fill your ListView). Your code should look like this afterwards:

```
HashMap<String, String> extractor = youListAdapter.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your parent `AdapterView` is designed for holding `int` values, they will be boxed automatically to `Integer`. That is why by calling `parent.getItemAtPosition(i)` you get `Integer`. Obviously, `Integer` cannot be casted to `HashMap`