# ERROR get item in ListView when OnClick item

Tags: android, listview, onclick

my name ari.. i am newbie in Android development. maybe you can help me to answer my problem. I want to display data from the listview adapter, but when i click the data. my app force close.

i have a adapter for show data in listview like :

**ListAdapter.java**

```
package com.santosa.sapasantosa.components;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.santosa.sapasantosa.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by muhammadaa on 10/14/2017.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private static ArrayList nik;
private static ArrayList nama;
private static ArrayList email;
private static ArrayList phone;
private static ArrayList jabatan;
private static ArrayList departement;
private static ArrayList gender;
private static ArrayList status;
private static ArrayList label;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public ListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList b, ArrayList c, ArrayList d, ArrayList e, ArrayList f, ArrayList g, ArrayList h, ArrayList i, ArrayList j) {
    activity = a;
    this.nik = b;
    this.nama = c;
    this.email = d;
    this.gender = e;
    this.status = f;
    this.label = g;
    this.phone = h;
    this.jabatan = i;
    this.departement = j;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return nik.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_data_profile, null);


        TextView nik2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profNik); // nik
        String ambilNik = nik.get(position).toString();
        nik2.setText(ambilNik);


        TextView nama2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profNama); // nama
        String ambilNama = nama.get(position).toString();
        nama2.setText(ambilNama);

        TextView email2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profEmail); // email
        String ambilEmail = email.get(position).toString();
        email2.setText(ambilEmail);

        TextView phone2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profPhone); // phone
        String ambilPhone = phone.get(position).toString();
        phone2.setText(ambilPhone);

        TextView gender2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profGender); // gender
        String ambilGender = gender.get(position).toString();
        gender2.setText(ambilGender);

        TextView bagian = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profBagian); // Bagian
        String ambilJabatan = jabatan.get(position).toString();
        String ambilDepartement = departement.get(position).toString();
        bagian.setText(ambilJabatan+"/"+ambilDepartement);

        TextView status2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profStatus); // status
        String ambilStatus = status.get(position).toString();
        status2.setText(ambilStatus);

        TextView label2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.countNumber); // label
        String ambilLabel = label.get(position).toString();
        label2.setText(ambilLabel);


    return vi;

}

}
```

And this class fragment for using adapter

**AdminHomeFragment**

```
package com.santosa.sapasantosa.view.admin;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.StringDef;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.santosa.sapasantosa.R;
import com.santosa.sapasantosa.components.ListAdapter;
import com.santosa.sapasantosa.components.RequestHandler;
import com.santosa.sapasantosa.components.SharedPrefManager;
import com.santosa.sapasantosa.configs.Constrant;
import com.santosa.sapasantosa.models.Employee;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
 public class AdminHomeFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ArrayList<String> nik_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> nama_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> email_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> phone_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> gender_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jabatan_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> departement_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> status_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> label_array = new ArrayList<>();
com.santosa.sapasantosa.components.ListAdapter adapter;


ListView listPeg;


public AdminHomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_home, container, false);

    listPeg = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.pegListView);
    listPeg.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),ProfileEmployeeActivity.class);

            HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Log.e("","adad "+map);
            String empId = map.get("nik");


            i.putExtra("nik",empId);


            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    loadDataPegawai();

    return view;
}



private void loadDataPegawai() {

    // get parameter
    final String users = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).getUserEmployee().getNik();

    class LoadPegawai extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", users);

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(Constrant.URL_PROFIL, params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);


            int n = 1;

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);


                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    // get data user dari respone
                    JSONArray userJson = obj.getJSONArray("user");

                    for (int i = 0, count = userJson.length(); i < count; i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = userJson.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (jsonObject.getString("employeeStatus").toString().equals("0")) {
                                nik_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeID").toString());
                                nama_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeNama").toString());
                                email_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeEmail").toString());
                                gender_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeGender").toString());
                                status_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeStatus").toString());
                                phone_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeePhone").toString());
                                jabatan_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeJabatan").toString());
                                departement_array.add(jsonObject.getString("employeeDepartement").toString());
                                label_array.add(n++);


                                String id = jsonObject.getString("employeeID").toString();
                                // adding to hashmap
                                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                                employees.put("nik",id);
                                list.add(employees);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    /* Set data to listview */
                    adapter = new com.santosa.sapasantosa.components.ListAdapter( getActivity(),
                            nik_array,
                            nama_array,
                            email_array,
                            gender_array,
                            status_array,
                            label_array,
                            phone_array,
                            jabatan_array,
                            departement_array);

                    listPeg.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listPeg.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //executing the async task
    LoadPegawai ru = new LoadPegawai();
    ru.execute();
}

}
```

when i clik data adapter in ListView, i have a Error like:

[image]

Can you help me for resolve the error. I say very very thanks you for your help...

Comment: you are returning an integer for `getItem(int position)` and integer is not a hashmap

Comment: parent.getItemAtPosition(position)  returns int value and you are trying to typecast in HashMap

Comment: Error message told you everything, you're trying to convert an integer to a HashMap, which is logically wrong.

Comment: what should I do @RRTW ?

Comment: I put a well format text into answer area...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886659/integer-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util-hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to display all employees as a ListView... If my understanding is't wrong, you should :

- Create an EmployeeBean
- Put all your employee into a collection...maybe ArrayList.

After that, when you click an item on ListView, the integer you get is the index of EmployeeBean in your collection, so that you can access it from your collection.

Comment: yes, i try to show all employee in ListView.. but when i want to show one employee. i have the error like that. Can you help me to resolve my code ?

Comment: When you click on an item of ListView, you'll get an index. And you should get your real data from your collection with the index you got from a click. All your real data was in that collection, not in ListView.